# Tool selection - is Celery the right system to use in this instance?

Tags: python, flask, celery

I have been trying to learn more about Celery, but it's difficult to understand what's literal in terms of "workers" and the "queue" and what it actually means in terms of programming. I apologize if this question is very basic, but I can't seem to find a straight answer in simple terms.

I have a Flask/Python app that I want to add a task assignment functionality to. For example, when one user completes a task, I want them to be able to flag it for their team members to check. Additionally, I'd like to be able to schedule task assignments, for example have a user complete 10 of a category of a task per week.

Celery seems like a good way to queue tasks and ensure that they are being completed, but the focus of this system seems to be scheduling resource intensive processes for asynchrous processing, not literal task assignment and queueing.

My question boils down to: is Celery the proper tool for assigning tasks to users, even if it's not for the purpose of resource saving? Have I misunderstood what the capabilities of Celery are? If so, what would be the tools to use to implement this feature?

Thank you!

Comment: Try it on a minimal *test* application and see if it suits your needs.  Please take the time to read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Celery is meant to for handling the queuing of automated tasks on computer workers. I recommend against using it for assigning tasks to your users.

If you're looking for a lightweight solution for storing queues of tasks for users, you could use lists in Redis: https://redis.io/topics/data-types

You could also probably use any database that you're already using.

Comment: This was the confusion I was having, when it comes to "workers", I was understanding it as human actors. This makes more sense. I already have a PostgreSQL server set up for handling user data and data input to the app so I'll probably try to figure it out using that at first, but may fall back on Redis. Thanks for the help!